# Constraints behave bizarre on iPhone X vs 8 (Xcode Bug?)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a tableView with custom cells which do look like cards.
Therefore I have a Normal UIView which contains the real cell content. This normal UIView has margin 8 into all directions for the distance between the card borders.

Now if I run the app on iPhone XR (As used in the layout inspector as "view-as", everything works fine). If I run it on iPhone 8 the cells run out of the right. Now if I select iPhone 8 as "view-as" and reset the constraints (set the value to 0 and back to 8) to 8 everywhere, it runs fine on iPhone 8 but when I run it on iPhone XR it has more distance on the right then 8.

Is this a bug or does xcode somehow save the "view-as" into the layout?

With "view-as" set to iPhone XR

**On iPhone XR**

[image]

**On Iphone 8**

[image]

Storyboard:
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLi2R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion above, please replace your `shadow` code with below code snippet inside `Cell` class -

```
  containerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: containerView.bounds).cgPath
  containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
  containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
  containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
  containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

**Complete code:**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        containerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: containerView.bounds).cgPath
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

}
```

Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: New solution seems to work. Could you tell me why you did use this solution?

Comment: @stealthcoders okay no issue :D. I've added the shadow code inside `Main` thread because while it's being initiated , the `frame` is coming from the `storyboard`, that's why the `containerView` didn't get its desired `frame`. Within `Main` thread it get its full frame according device screen width.

Comment: ah okay so the view gets initiated before the updated frame is coming from the storyboard?

Comment: yes the initial `frame` is coming from `storyboard` and then `GPU` calculate `frame` and `UI component` gets its desired size.

Comment: That's why whenever work on `CALayer or Shadow mask`, I recommend `IBDesignable and IBInspectable` for build time rendering. You can check here - https://medium.com/@nimjea/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-c12ea557b82b